# How enter in '.' first and then number in text of texfield?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I want enter float value in text field like as '.35'or '35' but not as '0..3678'.I want to restrict on enter of double dots. How do that?

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber* myNumber;
    NSString* myString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    range = NSMakeRange(0, [myString length]);
    [numberFormatter getObjectValue:&myNumber forString:myString range:&range error:nil];

    if (([myString length] > 0) && (myNumber== nil || range.length < [myString length])) {

        return NO;
    }else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I use above code for enter numeric value but it can't enter first dot/point and then number. What is error in above function?

Comment: i want restriction on double dots.

Answer (score 2):

```
int dots = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<[string length]; i++) {
    char test = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    if (test == '.') dots++;
}

if (dots > 1) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the character is the first character, check if it is a dot, and if it is, pass `0.` as the initial two characters in `myString`.